# Fetching user albums returns invalid cover picture

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When fetching the user albums (via me/albums?fields=id,name,picture,count), some albums return an icon (https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v1/yC/r/gtEJuZGrBLG.jpg) instead of the expected cover picture. It seems this only happens in shared albums with more than 1 contributor. I am the owner of these albums.

Adding a contributor to an album makes the album cover disappear from the response. Removing the contributor does not add it back.

The pictures count and the pictures inside the albums are fetched without any issues.

Comment: The "picture" parameter is an edge, not a field.  Facebook's graph API seems to always act a little weird when you try to use edges as fields.  Sometimes they work, sometimes they don't.  Instead, you might want to try something like this:

`/me/albums?fields=id,name,count,cover_photo{id,link}`

Comment: @user3268305, using your suggestion, I don't even get a cover_photo for the albums that previously had the icon as a cover photo. I reported this bug to Facebook and it seems it is a valid bug and will be fixed in the future.

Comment: it appears that   GET /{album-id}/picture  is doing the same thing

Comment: I got confirmation from Facebook that this is indeed a bug on their platform. Waiting for a fix.